# Horizontal Orientation not working with Ionic and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, android, ios, xml, cordova

I am trying to lock my screen orientation to horizontal view for the whole app always. I added a config.xml line that reads

but it doesn't have any affect when I test it. Does this need to be in a certain place in the xml, before or after other things? Also, I am testing using the Ionic lab view in the browser and the Ionic view app on my phone, could either of these not implement the xml?

Further more, I have also tried the cordova screen orientation plugin with no luck. Is this also because Ionic view app doesn't use the plug in for some reason? I end up with a white screen if I try my app with the plugin and Ionic view app. The code for that is just: screen.lockOrientation('landscape');

So finally, to sum up the questions:
config.xml doesn't work with the preference stated above, why?
Is Ionic view app not supporting my code fully? (ie. do they implement the app weird from there end)

Answer (score 0):

in AndroidManifest.xml, declare your Activity like so: `<activity ... android:screenOrientation="landscape" .../>`